# The relation between the declared type and created type

Tags: java, dynamic-binding

I have an question about the following code (Is this call dynamic binding?). I feel confused about 3 point.

First, what is the mean of the variable pq? Does pd still be the data type of P or be the Q?

Second, when I invoke the pq.m(pp) method, why the result become Q::P but not P::Q?

Finally, what is this mean ((P) qq).m(qq);? I hope somebody could solve my problem.

The result of the following code will be
P::Q,  Q::P,  Q::Q,  R::P,  Q::P,  Q::Q,  Q::Q

```
    class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        P pp  = new P();     
        Q qq  = new Q();
        R rr = new R();
        P pq  = qq;
        pp.m(qq);    
        pq.m(pp);  
        pq.m(qq);         
        rr.m(pp); 
        qq.m(pq);   
        qq.m(qq); 
        ((P) qq).m(qq);      
    }
}
class P {
    public void m(P p){System.out.println("P::P"); } 
    public void m(Q p){System.out.println("P::Q"); }
    public void m(R c){System.out.println("P::R"); }
}
class Q extends P {
    public void m(P p){System.out.println("Q::P"); } 
    public void m(Q p){System.out.println("Q::Q"); }
    public void m(R c){System.out.println("Q::R"); }
}
class R extends Q {
      public void m(P p){System.out.println("R::P"); } 
      public void m(Q p){System.out.println("R::Q"); }
    public void m(R c){System.out.println("R::R"); }
}
```

Comment: There is no variable `pd`, so it's difficult to answer your first question...

Comment: But to answer all your questions, you should read about [inheritance in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`P pq  = qq;` means that `pq` is known to the rest of the program as a type `P`. But as the creator, you know it's really of type `Q`. So this means that when you call `pq.m()`, it's really calling the implementation from class Q.

It's called overriding a method. So when you call pq.m(pp), you are really calling:
`public void m(P p){System.out.println("Q::P");` because that is the method from class Q.

If Q did not have a m(P) method, then it would automatically call the superclass method, the one from P.

`((P) qq).m(qq);` is the same as doing:

```
P pqq = (P)qq;   // pqq is known as P type, but it's instance is still the original Q type
pqq.m(qq); // Again, since pqq is truly an instance of Q, it calls Q.m(Q)
```

You should really read about inheritance. This is a bigger subject than can be explained here.

All this being said, your example doesn't illustrate its power well. But for example, if class Q had an extra method, `public void sayHello();`, then

```
Q q = new Q();
P p = new Q();
q.sayHello(); // This would be legal
p.sayHello(); // This would be illegal because the compiler knows p as a declared instance of P, even though you know it's truly a Q.
((Q)p).sayHello(); // This would be legal because you told the compiler to look at p as an instance of Q. It's called a cast.
```

I hope this all helps. Be sure to go read up on object orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Starting, I think you mean `pq`, not `pd`. Since Q extends P, Q is also a P type. It's like saying that an apple is a fruit. So you take the apple (Q) and says: It's a fruit (P). When you call the `pq` methods, they will call the methods from the Q class, since `pq` is still a Q object.
In the last part, when you do `((P) qq).m(qq);`, is the same as doing the following:

```
P p = (P) qq;
q.m(qq);
```

So as said above, the code will still call the method from the Q class, printing "Q::Q"

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic binding, and therefore polymorphism, only works for the object to the left of the dot in a method call (`o.m(x)` -- only for `o`). The arguments types are resolved statically, at compile time. Take a more well-known situation:

```
class A { 
  public boolean equals(A other) { 
    System.out.println("A.equals called"); return true;
  }
}

A a1 = new A(), a2 = new A();
Object o = a1;
o.equals(a1); // doesn't print anything
a1.equals(o); // doesn't print anything
a1.equals(a2); // prints "A.equals called"
```

The point here is that class A doesn't override Object.equals(Object), but instead just adds another overloaded method A.equals(A) -- and that one gets called only when the argument is of a declared type A.

Comment: sorry...i un-downvoted.  i found your explanation very confusing because i thought it sounded like you were describing c++ and not java.  the last paragraph you added improves your answer.